# Destroying array element + unlink file

Tags: php, file

after uploading files they get converted into a new array. im making a display function to display uploaded files + to destroy them on click

```
function display($type){
// echo $type;br();
// prettyR($_SESSION[$type]);
// echo"<hr>";
prettyR($_POST);
if(isset($_POST["del"])){
$p = $_POST["del"];
prettyR($_SESSION["misc"][$p]);
unlink($_SESSION["misc"][$p]["filename"]);
// $_SESSION["misc"][$p]["filename"] looks like this: upload/63eb3d2b83068_misc.jpg
unset($_SESSION["misc"][$p]);
}
echo"<form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='ka'></form>";
// this form is here so that the other forms work, because the display is in another form
if($type == "misc"){
    // echo"<hr>";
    // echo"hi";
    foreach($_SESSION[$type] as $file){
        echo"<hr>";
        // echo"hi";
        echo $file["name"];
        $key = $file["type"];
        echo"<form method='post'> <input type='hidden' value='$key' name='del'>";
        echo"<input type='submit'>";
        echo"</form>";
    }
}
}
```

but instead this message appears

**Warning**: Undefined array key "63eb3d2b83c20" in

im expecting this function to delete the files from the folder and to unset the informations from the misc array

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? You don't write anything to the session in the given code

Comment: for clarification: the files get converted into a new array, example they all are in a new session array $_SESSION["misc"]. the files are distinguished by an uniqid. my problem is that even though this works on the client page it still pops up a error message

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important stuff

Comment: This needs _a lot_ better explanation, of what is actually supposed to happen here. Right now, we don't even see where that function `display` actually gets called. What is _"this form is here so that the other forms work, because the display is in another form"_ supposed to actually mean? All of your forms do not have an `action` attribute, so they submit to the current URL. And which data you actually got in your session, and how it was supposed to get there, also unclear.

Comment: 1. the display function gets called after the arrays get created. my plan is that after they get displayed after getting uploaded. problem is that they do get displayed, they do get but on the client page it says that this array key doesnt exist.

Comment: `$key = $file["type"]` - I am guessing this value is not actually identical to the actual key that this particular $file is stored under in your session? But you are trying to _use_ that value, to access it in your session - `$_SESSION["misc"][$p]`. If you want to be able to access your session entries via their key, then `$key = $file["type"];` should be removed, and the loop instead be made into `foreach($_SESSION[$type] as $key => $file)`

Comment: 2. for more context: this is a page to upload files. one of the inputs can upload multiple files. after they get uploaded they get filtered by size, type and then get uploaded to a folder if they are valid, all kind of stuff that is not related to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifound the answer: ive been using a live server on vscode. that means right after the files get deleted the page reloads again, that means that the web server tries to unset something that doesnt exist. im sorry for my bad explenation, english istn my native language

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).